# Private key is not valid, when trying to access as-create-launch-config

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, certificate

I installed my ec2 tools in my command line. I can use it for creating a new instance and other similar operations. Now I wish to play with the [auto_scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2535) tool.

I installed it and edited my `.bashrc` profile. But when I try to issue commands like :

```
as-create-launch-config {your_launch_config_name} --image-id {your_ami_id} --instance-type t1.micro --key {your_access_key} --group {your_group_name}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
as-create-launch-config:  Malformed input-The content of the file: /opt/privateKey.pem, is not a valid
 private key
Usage:
as-create-launch-config
        LaunchConfigurationName  --image-id  value  --instance-type  value
       [--block-device-mapping  "key1=value1,key2=value2..." ]
       [--iam-instance-profile  value ]
       [--monitoring-enabled/monitoring-disabled  ] [--kernel  value ] [--key 
       value ] [--ramdisk  value ] [--group  value[,value...] ] [--spot-price 
       value ] [--user-data  value ]  [General Options]
For more information and a full list of options, run "as-create-launch-config --help"
```

I use the same private key for ec2 command line tools, that works. I created the certificate by following the instruction from [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html).

Where I'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your private key to pkcs8 format to see if it works:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in /opt/privateKey.pem -nocrypt > /opt/privateKey-temp.pem
mv /opt/privateKey-temp.pem /opt/privateKey.pem
```